# Cannot change hidden column state from true to false on setState

Tags: reactjs, state, setstate

I'm using devexpress React table and you can hide and show columns via state.

I would like to change the state for hidden from true to false but I get an Uncaught Invariant Violation error.

I've tried to use setState but doesn't work.

```
class ResultsTable extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        columns: [
            { name: 'agent', title: 'Agent' },
            { name: 'alertGroup', title: 'Alert Group', hidden:true },
            { name: 'manager', title: 'Manager', hidden:true }
            ],
        };
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        this.testAlert();
    }

    testAlert = () => {
        if (this.props.alertgroupColumn()) {
            this.setState({
                columns: [{ name: 'alertGroup', title: 'Alert Group', hidden:false }]
            })
        }
    }
```

Hidden should change from true to false.

Comment: Provide more details, please. Where did you  call setState?

Comment: Apologies - just amended the code.

Comment: It is still not clear where you are calling setState. Pleae provide the whole block of code.

Comment: Also in above code, you will end up removing the other two items from the columns array. Not sure if that is the intended behavior?

Comment: Well I'm only interested in ensuring this particular column's state of hidden changes from true to false atm.

Comment: It sounds as if your second code block is within one of the methods that the error mentions, which will potentially cause an infinite loop, hence the maximum update depth part of the error message.

Comment: in which function you're calling the setState

Comment: inside componentdidmount or your own function ?

Comment: My own function but componenDidMount() would probably be a better shout. Putting it into a function doesn't do much - the error goes away but it doesn't set the state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have another alternative to update your state

```
  class ResultsTable extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
            columns: [
                { name: 'agent', title: 'Agent' },
                { name: 'alertGroup', title: 'Alert Group', hidden:true },
                { name: 'manager', title: 'Manager', hidden:true }
                ],
            };
        }


        componentDidMount() {
            this.testAlert();
        }

        testAlert = () => {
            if (this.props.alertgroupColumn()) {
//---- get the columns from state 
   let columns = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.columns))
 columns[1].hidden = false
 this.setState({
      columns:columns 
    })  
                this.setState({
                    columns: [{ name: 'alertGroup', title: 'Alert Group', hidden:false }]
                })
            }
        }
```